# php default classes not working in magento

Tags: magento2, php, core, issue

I trying to sort cart item by price

```
private function getSortedItems($quote, $rule)
{

    $items = $this->context->getMatchingItems($quote, $rule);
    $itemObject = new ArrayObject($items);
    // Sort and print the resulting array
    $itemObject->uasort(function($a, $b) {
        return $a->getPrice() - $b->getPrice();
    });

    foreach ($itemObject as $itm) {
        print_r($itm->getPrice());exit(" <= price");
    }

    return $itemObject;
}
```

but its call me

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Vendor\MyModule\Rule\ArrayObject' not found in /home/public_html/app/code/Vendor/MyModule/Rule/AwaBuyGetFixed.php:117 Stack trace: #0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following way:

```
$itemObject = new \ArrayObject($items);
```

Comment: Thanks @Sohel Rana